# how to show my dynamic data on HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I already succeed accessing all the data needed to be shown like show below: [image]

and then I use this function but it won't show anything on the page. I dont knwo what's wrong. I already tested with document.write and my function works. The class name is right too.

```
function displayPokemon(pokemon) {
    console.log(pokemon)
    // document.write(5 + 6);
    document.querySelector(".pokemonBox").innerHTML = `
                    <div>
                        <img src="${pokemon.image}"
                        alt="${pokemon.name}"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="pokemonInfo">
                        <h2>${capitalizeFirstLetter(pokemon.name)}</h2>
                        <p>Height: ${pokemon.height}</p>
                        <p>Weight: ${pokemon.weight}</p>

                        <ul>
                            <li>${pokemon.abilities}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>${pokemon.types}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                `
}
```

This is the file on index.html:

```
<body>
     <main>
      <div class="searchBox">
        <input
          id="pokemonName"
          type="Pokemon name"
          placeholder="Pokemon name"
        />
        <button id="search"></button>
      </div>

      <div class="pokemonBox"></div>
    </main>
</body>
```

I call displayPokemon() inside this function:

```
async function getPokemon(e) {
    try {

        const name = document.querySelector('#pokemonName').value
        const nameLowerCase = lowerCaseName(name)
        const response = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=0&limit=100")
        const data = await response.json()
        const pokemons = await data.results

        pokemons.forEach(async (pokemon, i) => {
            const pokemonUrl = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i + 1}`)
            const pokemonDetails = await pokemonUrl.json()
            const abilityList = await pokemonDetails.abilities
            const typeList = await pokemonDetails.types

            if (nameLowerCase == pokemon.name) {
                const pokemonDataToShow = await {
                    name: pokemon.name,
                    image: pokemonDetails.sprites.other["official-artwork"].front_default,
                    height: pokemonDetails.height,
                    weight: pokemonDetails.weight,
                    abilities: abilityList.map((el) => el.ability.name).join(', '),
                    types: typeList.map((el) => el.type.name).join(', ')
                }
                // console.log(pokemonDataToShow)
                return displayPokemon(pokemonDataToShow)
            }
            else {
                document.querySelector(".pokemonBox").innerHTML = `
            <h> Pokemon not found </h >
        `
                // console.log("Pokemon not found");
            }
        })

    } catch (error) {
        // document.querySelector(".pokemonBox").innerHTML = `
        //     <h> Pokemon not found </h >
        // `
        console.log(error);
    }

    e.preventDefault();

}
```

Comment: where do you call displayPokemon function?

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi you can see in the question, i already edited it

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work here, did you write the function `capitalizeFirstLetter` somewhere, because it may be what is causing an error if you didn't.

```js
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function displayPokemon(pokemon) {
    console.log(pokemon)
    // document.write(5 + 6);
    document.querySelector(".pokemonBox").innerHTML = `
                    <div>
                        <img src="${pokemon.image}"
                        alt="${pokemon.name}"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="pokemonInfo">
                        <h2>${capitalizeFirstLetter(pokemon.name)}</h2>
                        <p>Height: ${pokemon.height}</p>
                        <p>Weight: ${pokemon.weight}</p>

                        <ul>
                            <li>${pokemon.abilities}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>${pokemon.types}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                `
}
displayPokemon({
  'name' : 'Pikachu',
  'image' : 'img',
  'height' : 0.3,
  'weight' : 0.5,
  'abilities' : ['attack1','attack2'],
  'types' : 'elec'
});
```

```html
<body>
     <main>
      <div class="searchBox">
        <input
          id="pokemonName"
          type="Pokemon name"
          placeholder="Pokemon name"
        />
        <button id="search"></button>
      </div>

      <div class="pokemonBox"></div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: oh, my mistake is i should've not use the else after if! Anyway, thank you for your help!